# Eassily create a logger in python for many modules with loglevel set according to command line arguments

Tags: python, logging, modules

I'm trying to learn writing python programs in a modular way as much as possible. One of the issues I've had difficulty to solve is parsing command line arguments (with `argparse`) and having a `logger` object in all my modules which it's `name` will be the `__name__` of the module and it's log level identical across all modules.

I've even posted a [question on Sstack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822477/logging-with-the-same-logging-levels-accross-modules) where I describe the problem more thoroughly but I would like to gain some confidence with the solution I've constructed before posting an answer to my own question.

This is the scheme I've come up with:

#### `core/__init__.py`:

```
from .argpconf import Argpconf

import logging
argpconf = Argpconf()
_loglevel = argpconf.get_loglevel()
class Logger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, level=_loglevel):
        self.name = name
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, level)
        self.addHandler(argpconf.get_loghandler())
```

#### `core/argpconf.py`:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import logging

class Argpconf():
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Define command line arguments parser
        """
        self.argp = ArgumentParser(
            description="Generator for shell, ranger and vim commands for fzf based shortcuts"
        )
        self.argp.add_argument(
            '-v', '--verbose',
            dest='verbosity',
            default=2,
            action='count',
            help='increase verbosity, use multiple times to increase more'
        )
        self.args = vars(self.argp.parse_args())
    def get_loglevel(self):
        # Convert logging level to the proper scale
        logging_level = self.args['verbosity'] * 10
        # make sure a level higher then 50 won't be passed to setLevel
        logging_level = min(logging_level, 50)
        # reverse the numbers of so a higher verbosity will set a higher log level
        logging_level = 60 - logging_level
        return logging_level
    def get_logformat(self):
        if self.args['verbosity'] > 2:
            return logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        else:
            return logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    def get_loghandler(self):
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(self.get_logformat())
        return handler
```

#### Every other file that would like to use a `logger`:

```
from core import Logger
logger = Logger(__name__)

...
```

### Notes

- The `Logger` class defined in `core/__init__.py` is based on [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1326).
- The function `get_logformat` from `Argpconf` sets a different format for the messages so in debugging modes the `__name__` and `levelname` will be included, according to the verbosity set in the command line.

Comment: Your code will not compile: `argpconf.get_loglevel()` is not defined.  I assume you have "simplified" the code for posting to "Code Review", but ended up removing too much.  You need to provide complete working code, or your question will be put on hold and/or closed.